# Add user data on product image in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization

I am using wordpress, in which there is a multistep form which user fill and select product image, which image user select all data should come on that product image.

Comment: question not clear. what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to know how to get data entered in the form on the template selected by user

Comment: you are using tabs. so you get by form serilize() in jquery.

Comment: yes....but  the data which user fill how can get it on 3rd step

Comment: the background and template change on the basis of selection of image  made by user in 2 nd step

Comment: you mean logged in user data?

Comment: no.....the data that is filled by user in 1st and 2nd step

Comment: post your code here or create a fiddle.